# SQL Error 8115 Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in my sql table with

```
MIN_PRICE(NUMERIC(38,10),NULL)
```

I want to insert these values into my temp table which is also having a column

```
MIN_PRICE(NUMERIC(38,10), NULL)
```

but while inserting values getting error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 28
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Comment: Please put what you tried...

Comment: havent tried anything special,just started to insert values with `INSERT` query and got the error

Comment: And what values might that be?

Comment: @Rohan Put your query here.

Comment: values are like `8.9000000000  
1.3000000000  
1.4500000000`

Comment: @RohanS post your insert query also, issue might be in that as values you have given are valid for given numeric column.

Comment: What is `MIN_PRICE`? If it's a UDF, it might be some calculation internal to it that's hitting the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You may be inserting data which is exceeding the limit 38 digits to the left and 10 digits after right after the decimal point.Probably this may occur when you perform operations on aggregate or like-wise functions.So,better check all the declared variables are compatible or not.

Answer (score -1):

try this if you are using SQL server. It will take null value whenever you are not passing any value to MIN_PRICE column.

```
declare @table table (
MIN_PRICE NUMERIC(38,10) NULL
)
```